# create a JSON array object- grouping by the same date into a new array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm thinking how to group my array by objects with the same date.
I have this result from MySQL query(select DateTime ,ip,Val from my table):

```
  DateTime                 ip                       Val
2017-02-01 08:00:23       10.10.10.1                2
2017-02-01 09:01:23       10.10.10.2                3
2017-02-01 12:02:23       10.10.10.3                4
2017-02-02 13:03:23       10.10.10.4                5
2017-02-03 15:04:23       10.10.10.5                6
2017-02-03 20:05:23       10.10.10.6                7
```

from mysql query result to create json array object as below ,

```
$sql = "select DateTime ,ip,Val from my table order by DateTime ASC ;";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$data = array();
$rowary = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $rowary['DateTime'] = $row['DateTime '] ;
    $rowary['ip'] = $row['ip'] ;
    $rowary['Val'] = $row['Val'] ;
    $data[$i++]=$rowary;
  }
echo '<pre>' . var_export($data, true) . '</pre>';
```

Is it possible to  create a JSON array object that group by the same date If I use

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($Data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);?>
```

in javascript,

expected result is:

```
 [
    [
      {
         "DateTime": "2017-02-01 08:00:23",
         "ip": "10.10.10.1",
         "Val": "2"
      },
      {
         "DateTime": "2017-02-01 09:01:23",
         "ip": "10.10.10.2",
         "Val": "3"
      },
      {
         "DateTime": "2017-02-01 12:02:23",
         "ip": "10.10.10.3",
         "Val": "4"
      }
   ],
   [
     {
        "DateTime": "2017-02-02 13:03:23",
        "ip": "10.10.10.4",
        "Val": "5"
     }
   ],
   [
    {
       "DateTime": "2017-02-03 15:04:23",
       "ip": "10.10.10.5",
       "Val": "6"
    },
    {
       "DateTime": "2017-02-03 20:05:23",
       "ip": "10.10.10.6",
       "Val": "7"
    }
   ]

 ]
```

How can I create a JSON array object that group by the same date?

Comment: Unclear, what is the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry . I have make the question more clear .

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: I have add expected result

Comment: Please check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get data from mySQL in **asc** or **dsc** order, Then do like this:-

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'DateTime' => '2017-02-01 08:00:23',
        'ip'       => '10.10.10.1',
        'Val'       => '1'
    ),
    array(
        'DateTime' => '2017-02-01 09:01:23',
        'ip'       => '10.10.10.2',
        'Val'       => '2'
    ),
    array(
        'DateTime' => '2017-02-02 09:01:23',
        'ip'       => '10.10.10.3',
        'Val'       => '3'
    ),
    array(
        'DateTime' => '2017-02-02 13:03:23',
        'ip'       => '10.10.10.4',
        'Val'       => '4'
    ),
    array(
        'DateTime' => '2017-02-03 15:04:23',
        'ip'       => '10.10.10.5',
        'Val'       => '5'
    ),
    array(
        'DateTime' => '2017-02-03 20:05:23',
        'ip'       => '10.10.10.6',
        'Val'       => '6'
    ),
);

$FirstDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($a[0]['DateTime']));
$output = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($a as $value){

    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['DateTime']));

    if($currentDate != $FirstDate){
        $i++;
        $FirstDate = $currentDate;
    }       

    $output[$i][] = $value;

}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Ashutosh, I  have try to create the array ,then do like as you said ,but still cannot get the results that i want . I have add create array code in  my question

Answer (score 0):

This could be in Javascript

You can use UnderscoreJS library for this refer http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

You can do like this

"var a = [
         {
        'DateTime' :'2017-02-01 08:00:23',
        'ip'       :'10.10.10.1',
        'Val'      : '1'
         },

```
     {
    'DateTime' :'2017-02-01 09:01:23',
    'ip'       :'10.10.10.2',
    'Val'      : '2'
     },

     {
    'DateTime' :'2017-02-02 09:01:23',
    'ip'       :'10.10.10.3',
    'Val'      : '3'
    },

     {
    'DateTime' :'2017-02-02 13:03:23',
    'ip'       :'10.10.10.4',
    'Val'      : '4'
    },

     {
    'DateTime' :'2017-02-03 15:04:23',
    'ip'       :'10.10.10.5',
    'Val'      : '5'

    },

     {
    'DateTime' :'2017-02-03 20:05:23',
    'ip'       :'10.10.10.6',
    'Val'      : '6'
    }];
```

Then user _.groupBy function like this

_.groupBy(a, function(obj){ return new Date(obj.DateTime).toDateString() });"

Hope it will help you